# RFID Conversion hexadecimal to decimal

Tags: math, hex

How do I convert this hexadecimal code to decimal: `5A 95 62 80`?
And also this one: `67 64 07 68`?
I need this to use in an `if` statement.

Comment: Just stick the hex code into a calculator such as the free one in Windows in hex mode then click the radio button for decimal.

Comment: There are plenty of websites that will convert any hex number to decimal (such as https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter), but if you are using the normal Arduino environment you don't have to. Just write the number in hexadecimal, like this: 0X5A956280UL (note that you need the UL suffix even if you use the decimal value). By the way I'm assuming that you mean a single 8 hex-digit  number, not a series of four separate hex numbers?

Comment: If you need to use a hex value "5A 95 62 80" in an if statement then just do `if (thing == 0x5A956280)`. There's no "conversion" necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I'll do one example:

Say you have the hexadecimal number 6B.

That's 6 in the 16's place and 11 in the 1's place.

So

$$6B_{16} = 6\times16 + 11 = 107$$

Based on that example, you should be able to solve all of your examples yourself.